# Proving symmetry in an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and let $a,b \in G$. Define the relation $\equiv$ on $G$ by $a\equiv b$ if and only if $ab^{-1} \in H$. Show that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $G$.

Well my only question is in the symmetry part. This is what I did.

NTS.
If $a\equiv b$ then $b \equiv a$.

$a\equiv b \Rightarrow ab^{-1} \in H$

$\Rightarrow (ab^{-1})^{-1}\in H$ since inverse exist if H is a subgroup

$\Rightarrow a^{-1}b \in H$

$\Rightarrow ba^{-1} \in H$  *Can I do this? Can I commute an inverse?

Comment: Fortunately $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=ba^{-1}$. Equality $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=ab^{-1}$ is not true in general.

Comment: @dhrab How? I dont get it. Dont we follow the rules of exponential distibution (which is the same for groups)?

Comment: You are assuming commutativity here as well. You can't.

Comment: $ab^{-1}ba^{-1}=aea^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e=bb^{-1}=beb^{-1}=ba^{-1}ab^{-1}$

Comment: @dhrab that is much clearer. thank you very much.

Comment: @llawliet_78 "the rules of exponential distribution" do not apply to non-commutative groups.  For example,
$(ab)^2 = abab$, but $a^2b^2 = aabb$.  These two can only be equal if $ab = ba$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you so much for the point out!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't assume commutativity -and you don't need to: $ab^{-1}\equiv h\in H\Longleftrightarrow a=hb\Longleftrightarrow e=hba^{-1}\Longleftrightarrow h^{-1}=ba^{-1}\in H$

Comment: If this did answer your question it would be nice if you'd accept it. If there is however some things still unclear, let me know. Thanks.